# Java: Array with loop(matches)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I need to find the first match in this task. Probably i am just missing something. As you can see, i found the last match.I am not copied the first half of the code. Thank you.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    if (iv[i] == a) {
        hely = i;
    }
}
if (hely == -1) {
    System.out.println("text");
} else {
    System.out.println("text " + a + " text " + (hely + 1) + "text");
}
```

Comment: Too ambiguous. Try to give some expected input and output.

Comment: You just need to exit out of your loop when you find a first match, no need to continue looping after first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

break the loop when you find first match.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    if (iv[i] == a) {
        hely = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to exit the for loop after finding the first match:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    if (iv[i] == a) {
        hely = i;
        break;
    }
}
```